# How can i make a button that when click download the app's lastest content?

Tags: react-native

I'm making a city guide app. I want to make it working offline as well and also want to make an admin panel to edit or add new pages etc. So i was planning to make a button that when something is updated on the server,  when we click a button in the app it will download the lastest contents and use it unil the next update. For the admin panel updates, i'm planning to  make a website and convert it to app but i'm not sure if i can take a snapshot of the website and use it offline too. If someone have a idea about how can i aproach to this problem i'd be so glad. I'm very new at react-native  and mobile app development. Thank you

Comment: Did you try maintaining a version of the content? whenever you update your content, locally store the current version of the content and on click of the button, you could check from your server what was the latest version available and compare with the local one. if you find a difference in the version. you could download the content. Please note: don't check if the version is greater in server and then download, because you might end up in a situation where you wanted to revert back to your older version that way you could use that as well. if u mean app-update it has complete different flow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  is there any method or callback that help me to locally store the data in react native? basicly how can i make the content download and use that data in app? I dont want  app update do app update for every screen i add. All i need it  able to download the  lastest data and use it

Comment: Ok. you could use `AsyncStorage` but it has a limitation of 6MB max to store. if your content is going to be more than 6MB, you could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage (I haven't tried it myself but heard it is a good choice)

Comment: dude you are awesome! thanks a lot! you saved me from big problem